# Inline style with webkit text stroke not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

```
<div className="headdingtextcon"><h1>The Best Things In Life Are</h1><span className="sidehome" style={{-webkit-text-stroke:'1px solid white'}}>SWEET!</span></div>
```

I am trying to make an inline css style with webkit text stroke. It gives a cannot find a cannot find -webkit-text-stroke error.

If i do this which is making webkit a string it dosent work how to do webkit as an inline style?

```
<div className="headdingtextcon"><h1>The Best Things In Life Are</h1><span className="sidehome" style={{'-webkit-text-stroke':'1px solid white'}}>SWEET!</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For React elements the property is named:
`WebkitTextStroke`

```js
<div style={{ WebkitTextStroke: 2, WebkitTextStrokeColor: "grey" }}>{"text"}</div>
```